# Capturing terminal-content from a pseudoterminal (pts)?

Tags: command-line, tty, xterm

On Ubuntu, is there a way to capture the *content* of a pseudoterminal (pts - eg. /dev/pts/4) - ie. dump the lines of text in the terminal to a file - of a program that's *already running* in that terminal?  I'm not talking about taking a screenshot, but storing what the program is writing to the terminal to a file.  It's a *curses-based* program, that regularly rewrites the screen.

My main problem, is that my program is *already running* - and I'd like to store this *before* stopping (and perhaps restarting) the program.

I know there are several ways to accomplish this is I'd thought about this possibility *before* I started the program:  Simply redirecting the output to a file; using `screen`, and taking a hardcopy or logging the session; using a virtual terminal instead (/dev/tty..) and using the video console memory device (/dev/vcs..); using the command `script`... (and probably many others...)

But all of this, would only have worked if I did it before I started the program!

So, is there still a way I could "snoop" on the pseudoterminal and record it's content?  I can become root if I have to...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1323956/how-to-redirect-output-of-an-already-running-process?

Comment: most of the answers (which are tangentially applicable, really) are coming at this from the angle of how to intercept output to a terminal or from a process. this isn't quite what you're asking for though. what you want is something like tmux's capture-pane... and i would expect that either screen or featureful teminal emulators could also provide you with this kind of feature.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not directly from the tty, but this processus has to use the `write` syscall. You can use `strace` to catch all write calls.

```
sudo strace -e t=write -s 6000 -p your-process-id 2>logfile
```

You will get things like this, that might need some more parsing :

```
write(1, "191\n", 4)                    = 4
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=9916, si_uid=1001, si_status=0, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
write(1, "21021\n", 6)                  = 6
write(1, "14728\n", 6)                  = 6
write(1, "13291\n", 6)                  = 6
write(1, "20372\n", 6)                  = 6
```

If your program writes to some other files, you'll get that too in the output. That can be annoying. Or that eventually could be a huge amount of data.
The file descriptor used is probably 1. You can grep "^write.1"

```
sudo strace -e t=write -s 6000 -p your-process-id 2>&1 | grep ^write.1 >logfile
```

---

Next time, try to run you command with `script`. It catches all data written to the tty.

```
script -c "program and args" logfile
```